# How to Free Memory when Out-of-memory exception occurs in Delphi using SetLength

Tags: delphi, memory, free, multidimensional-array

I have a piece of Delphi code

```
var
  a: array of array of array of integer;
begin
  try
   SetLength(a, 100000, 100000, 10000); // out of memory here
   doStuffs(a); 
  except
   a = nil; // try to free the memory 
  end;
end;
```

The above code tries to allocate lots of memory and `out-of-memory` will be caught. The `a=nil` will be executed, but the memory isn't freed.

Is there a way to free the memory in the case of out-of-memory exception?

I tried `SetLength(a, 0, 0, 0)` and `Finalize(a)`, and both won't work either.

Comment: When you're in the exception handler, does `a` even have a non-null value? If not, then you can hardly expect to be able to free it. Besides, it will be freed at the end of the function anyway. Have you confirmed that `SetLength` sets the `a` variable when it can't finish allocating all the requested memory?

Comment: @Rob No, `a` is `nil` in the exception handler.

Comment: Yes, a=nil when the code steps into the exception block. PS: I used the FastMM as the memory manager.

Comment: And in this case, the memory is not freed unless the program exits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, it's not possible to recover from an out of memory error. At that point the heap is most likely corrupted. The appropriate response is to terminate the process.

In this specific case, the allocation is performed by `DynArraySetLength` in the `System` unit. This performs repeated allocations. Only as the last act of `DynArraySetLength` is the return value, `a` in your code above, actually assigned. And if errors occur in `DynArraySetLength` then the runtime makes no effort to tidy up. Which means that in case of failure, any memory allocated is leaked and cannot be recovered. You have no way to refer to it in order to free it.

You may think that `DynArraySetLength` should do more to tidy up. However, it's approach is justifiable. Since out of memory conditions invariably result in corrupt heap, attempts to tidy up would just prolong the agony. Once the heap is dead, there's no point in trying to deallocate memory.

Comment: The natural follow-up question is 'Is there a `TrySetLength` procedure?'

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand No there is not.

Comment: Are you sure? It think it depends on memory manager internals whether heap is corrupted or not.

Comment: @Serg Not in the case of SetLength for multi-dim arrays. And I honestly don't think any of the commonly used MMs are resilient to OOM.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand you could create such a function, but then you'd need to write your own `DynArraySetLength` to be much more robust. A more simple (but not race condition proof) approach is to check if the memory is available, then allocate it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan maybe Pierre le Riche could shed some light on OOM resilience. He is the author of FastMM which is the default Delphi memory manager.